# Can we make API call to set the initial state of reducer?

Tags: reactjs, reduce

```
let initialData = {
 products:[]
}

const ItemReducer = (state = initialData, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCHDATA":
      return {
        ...state,
        products: action.payload,
      };
  }
 return state;
}


let [productdata, setProductdata] = useState();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(()=>{
  axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
  .then((res) => setProductdata(res.data))
  .catch((err) => console.log("error"))
},[]);
dispatch({type:"FETCHDATA",payload: productdata});
```

Initial state of ItemReducer must contain the "product details" which needs to be fetch from api call. While am using the above code, its returning undefined.

Comment: You should try to call an api in the app.js and try to add initial state to the reducer.

Comment: what is your resp for `res.data`?

Comment: Hi @HritikSharma, I have called my API in app.js and stored the response in to local Storage. Then set the initial state of reducer from localstorage. Apart from this is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to do the fetch in a parent component and only render the children (that has the `useDispatch`) when the productData is present. That way it can also handle error and loading states, something like this:

```
const ProductDetailsList = ({ products }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "FETCHDATA", payload: products });
  }, [dispatch])

  return <div>...</div>;
};

const ProductsDetails = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    axios
      .get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
      .then((res) => setProducts(res.data))
      .catch(setError)
      .finally(() => setLoading(false))
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
  }

  return <ProductDetailsList products={products} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Related to the docks you have to use

```
fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(json=>console.log(json))
```